# Retrieve User Object form following String?

Tags: java, android, json, string, sharedpreferences

```
 [
    "User{id='0', username='f', password='f'}",
    "User{id='0', username='t', password='t'}",
    "User{id='0', username='uma', password='uma'}"
 ]
```

I create ShaerdPreferences database to  store User object . following code do that stuff, and now I want to retrieve User object within ***`getUser method`***. I used several method to do this but given error.I still couldn't take User object from above string . please wish some expert help to do this.

Full Code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class PreferenceUtils {


    /**
     * Save user credentials in shared preference
     *
     * @param context application context
     * @param user    logged-in user
     */
    private static ArrayList<String> userDetail;


    public static void saveUser(Context context, User user) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        if (null == userDetail) {
            userDetail = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        userDetail.add(user.toString());
        JSONArray jsonAraay = new JSONArray(userDetail);
        editor.putString("User", String.valueOf(jsonAraay));

        .

        editor.commit();
    }


    /**
     * Get user details from shared preference
     *
     * @param context application context
     * @return user object
     */
    public static User getUser(Context context) throws NoUserException {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String userlist= preferences.getString("User","");
        Log.e("object" , userlist);

        //take user object and return


        return new User("id ","UserName","Password");




    }



}
```

Comment: To be a JSON, your parameters need double quotes like 
[
  {"id"="0", "username"="f", "password"="f"}
]

Comment: The output seems an Array of String, and the String seems not in JSON format

Comment: @KNeerajLal is it wrong early step i added to data to JsonArray ??? Are there any way to me split about sting and retrieve UserName and Password Separately ??

Comment: I think the easiest method would be to use GSON.

Comment: @S.W. how i can my object write that json formate ?

Comment: If you need to parse out the parameter in a hard code way,
simply split each string by ( ' ), and take array[1],[3],[5]

Comment: @uma I agree with K NeeRaj Lal that if you are new to JSON, using Gson library will be your best choice for fast implementation, with Gson, what you need is just a model class and a code "new Gson().toJson(you object here);"

Comment: @S.W. when new user adding , add more data to file. really i want when user login retrieval user name and password. i want to match given username and password with this string username and password.so , i this , hard code may be wrong.???

Comment: @S.W. i am very beginner of programing. i should change my saveuser method ? can you please give me example?

Comment: @uma, it will have wrong phasing if the id/username/password have (')

Comment: @uma Check out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library for this.

Add gson to your project by adding it as a `jar` or as a gradle dependency. [This](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) is the user guide for GSON.
Add this to your `build.gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

To Save,

```
public static void saveUser(Context context, User user) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    if (null == userDetail) {
        userDetail = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    userDetail.add(user.toString());
    editor.putString("User", new Gson().toJson(userDetail));
    editor.commit();
}
```

Import for `TypeToken` is as follows.

```
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
```

To retrieve,

```
public static List<User> getUser(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String userlist= preferences.getString("User","");
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType();
    userDetail = new Gson().fromJson(userlist, collectionType);
    return userDetail;
}
```

You can also modify the `getUser` method to get a particular `User` object from the list as follows.

```
public static User getUser(Context context, String id) throws NoUserException {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String userlist= preferences.getString("User","");
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType();
    userDetail = new Gson().fromJson(userlist, collectionType);
    for (User user : userDetail) {
        if(user.getID().equals(id)){
            return user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank You answer. But  new Gson() , not imported ? i code using android studio. i should import some library ???

Comment: add this to your gradle 
compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'

Comment: @Thank i will try this and come with feed back.

Comment: @S.W.  Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType(); given error and give mulitple solution to import , please let me know what i want to import to this ?

Comment: @S.W. The Error was gone when i change Arraylist type to -> User (ArrayList <User > list ) Thank for your help.